# Quickly display a color graphically

Tags: front-end, notebooks, output-formatting, color

When manipulating colors, the output is shown as a textual expression like `Hue[1/5]`, `RGBColor[2/3, 1, 1/3]`, `GrayLevel[3/5]`. It can be hard to visualize what color these represent.

How can you quickly display the color itself on screen?

Answer (score 11):

A simple way is to use a [`ColorSetter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorSetter.html).

Where `color` is the color you want to display, run

```
DynamicSetting@ColorSetter@color
```

You can also copy the result and [use it as input in a notebook](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html).

#### Illustration:

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 8):

Evaluate (Shift+Enter) your code for color. In Mathematica 9 the suggestion bar will appear under the output with suggestion "swatch". Just click it and you'll get a square with that color.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know what a particular color looks like and don't have M9 you can set it up with `Graphics` in many ways.  Here is one. I've added the `Listable` attribute so you can see many colors at once.

```
SetAttributes[swatch, Listable];
swatch[col_] := Graphics[{col, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 50]

swatch[{Hue[1/5], RGBColor[2/3, 1, 1/3], GrayLevel[3/5]}]
```

[image]